# Why non-blocking algorithm does not work correctly

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-threads, compare-and-swap

I am writing a thread safe counter. When I test and the threads go first one, then the second everything works correctly. But when threads enter the increment () method at the same time, the counter does not work properly. The reason is not clear, I am using atomic integer.

```
public class CASCount {

    private final AtomicReference<Integer> count = new AtomicReference<>(0);
    private AtomicInteger oldValue = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private AtomicInteger newValue = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public void increment() {

        do {
            oldValue.set(count.get());
            System.out.println(oldValue + " old");

            if (oldValue.get() == -1) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Count is not impl.");
            }
            newValue.incrementAndGet();
            System.out.println(newValue + " new");
        } while (!count.compareAndSet(oldValue.get(), newValue.get()));

    }

    public int get() {
        int result = -1;
        result = count.get();
        if (result == -1) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Count is not impl.");
        }
        return result;
    }
}

 @Test
    public void whenUseCASCount() throws InterruptedException {
        CASCount count = new CASCount();
        Thread one = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("one");
                count.increment();

            }

        });

        Thread two = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("two");
                count.increment();

            }

        });
        one.start();
        two.start();
        one.join();
        two.join();
        assertThat(count.get(), is(10));
    }
```

Comment: counter does not work properly - describing what is happening and what is expected would help SO to help you

Comment: I run the test and in the interval of adding 4 and 5, the cycle runs 2 times 4 old 5 new
4 old 5 new

Comment: expecting 10 but getting different numbers 9 , 11 , 14 for example

Comment: Add `synchronied` to the `increment` method.

Comment: If you make the method as synchronized then what is the point of using the non-blocking synchronization here? It solely defeats the original purpose. Moreover, you are using two different synchronization schemes which is odd.

Comment: @mnestorov That would completely defeat the purpose. What exactly do you think those `AtomicIntegers` and the `AtomicReference` are for?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**TL;DR** - Make your `increment` method `synchronized`.

---

**Details** - Even though you have `atomic` variables that you use, that does **not** mean that your class is thread safe. It's **not** safe because there can be (and are) race conditions between the checks and increments for your variables.

```
do {
    oldValue.set(count.get());
    System.out.println(oldValue + " old");

    if (oldValue.get() == -1) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Count is not impl.");
    }
    newValue.incrementAndGet();                                     <--- between here
    System.out.println(newValue + " new");
} while (!count.compareAndSet(oldValue.get(), newValue.get()));     <--- and here
```

A typical case of *check-then-act* race condition.

This happens because your atomic variables can be accessed by multiple threads and their shared state can mutate from one thread and not be seen in another.

> To preserve state consistency, update related state variables in a single
> atomic operation.
>
> - Java Concurrency in Practice

Hence, we use intrinsic locks (built-in `synchronized`) to make the method safe when multiple threads access it. What happens is that the state of the atomic variables would not change because each thread will access the `increment` method one at a time.

Comment: If you make the method as `synchronized` then what is the point of using the non-blocking synchronization here? It solely defeats the original purpose. Moreover, you are using two different synchronization schemes which is odd.

Comment: If you are referring to using atomic variables and intrinsic locks as odd, I would assume that plenty of people do that and I wouldn't necessarily consider that odd. As for the *efficiency* of the procedure and whether or not it should be this way, it's not up to US but to the OP. He has provided the code base and this in *one* way to solve his issue.

Comment: and this decision does not contradict non blocking algoritm ?

Comment: The concept of locking a specific code snippet is fine, there is a reason why java provides such mechanisms in it.... Whether or not this is the right/correct way to do your task for your specific case, you would be the better judge to that. If you are solely incrementing numbers like this, then asynchronous processing might not be the best choice, but there are plenty of cases where locking mechanisms work and make the code compliant with async-processes.

Answer (score 0):

its my decision

```
private final AtomicReference<Integer> count = new AtomicReference<>(0);

public void increment() {
    int current, next;
    do {
        current = count.get();
        next = current + 1;
    } while (!count.compareAndSet(current, next));
}

public int get() {
    return count.get();
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  Autoboxing an `int` does not guarantee to give the same `Integer` object each time.  But `compareAndSet` tests using `==` rather that `equals`.

Comment: (FWIW - the pragmatic solution is to just use an `AtomicInteger` and its `increment` method.)

Comment: Good point, I have missed it. Thanks for bringing this in. However the OPs intention seems to write an atomic counter himself, without using the out of the box `AtomicInteger` in my not so humble opinion.

Comment: how to uses it correctly if they use == and  equals ?

Comment: Change `int current, next;` to `Integer current, next;`. Then, the identity of the object returned by `count.get()` and assigned to `current` is guaranteed to be the same when passing it to `compareAndSet(current, next)`, so it will succeed if no concurrent update has happened.